# Static factory methods in JAXB MOXy

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am defining a static factory method with:

```
@XmlType(factoryClass=DummyFactory.class, factoryMethod="createNew")
public abstract MyClass() {
}
```

The reason I am using factory methods is that `MyClass` is abstract, and how to obtain an instance of it depends on certain annotations of the class. This logic is embedded in the factory method `createNew`.

In addition, the factory class `DummyFactory` is abstract. As far as I understand factory classes do not need to provide a default constructor if their factory method is static (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html).

This is a raw simplification of how the factory class looks like:

```
public abstract class DummyFactory {
    public static MyClass createNew() {
        // code for returning a new instance of MyClass
    }   
}
```

However, when I try to unmarshal a XML document, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-171] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The factory class does not define a public default constructor, or the constructor raised an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException
```

First I thought that I did not get something correctly in the explanation of factory classes and methods, but then I tried with JAXB RI and this is working fine there.
So my question is:

Is there a way to make MOXy work with abstract factory classes ?

(JAXB RI is giving me other kind of problems, that is the reason I would prefer not using it).

Comment: I'm the MOXy lead and this appears to be a bug.  Could you enter a bug for this issue:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink.  We should be able to get a fix in on Moday.

Comment: Done. Bug submitted: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362984 . Thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Comment: We've figured out the fix, we just need to flush out the testing.  I expect we will check in the fix tomorrow.

Comment: This same problem appears to be occurring again with version 3.7.4.  The only difference now is that it doesn't appear to match properly against a static factory method if the return value doesn't match exactly.  This prevents creating a reusable "dummy" factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for entering a bug for this issue (https://bugs.eclipse.org/362984).  The issue has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.4 stream, and will be backported today (Nov 9, 2011) to the EclipseLink 2.3.2 stream.  You can try out the fix obtaining a nightly download from:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Now if you specify a factory class using the `@XmlType` annotation like:

```
@XmlType(factoryClass=DummyFactory.class, factoryMethod="createNew")
public abstract MyClass() {
}
```

The following types of factory classes are supported:

**Factory with Static Methods**

With this bug fix, when MOXy uses the factory method to create an instance of `MyClass` an instance of `DummyFactory` is not created.

```
public abstract class DummyFactory {
    public static MyClass createNew() {
        // code for returning a new instance of MyClass
    }   
}
```

**Factory with Instance Methods**

In addition to static methods, MOXy allows you to specify instance level creation methods.  For these methods MOXy will create an instance of the factory class.

```
public class DummyFactory {
    public MyClass createNew() {
        // code for returning a new instance of MyClass
    }   
}
```

This configuration is not allowed in the JAXB RI, and you will get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Factory class "forum8022136.DummyFactory" does not have static zero args factory method "createNew".
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at forum8022136.MyClass

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at forum8022136.Demo.main(Demo.java:14)
```